# PayPal Payflow Pro Does Not Log All Payment Information and Also Auto Approves eCheck

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-payflow-pro

We previously were using “PayPal Payments Advanced“ Magento payment method to connect our online store to our PayPal account. We have recently switched to “Payflow Pro” Magento payment method because it offers the ability to enter credit card information without leaving the checkout page before confirming their order.

There are two downfalls with Payflow Pro:

1) PayFlow Pro does not send  Seller protection, AVS, etc back to us (see before and after screenshot below)

2) When customers checkout with the eCheck option, orders come straight through as processing which in turn is sent to our ERP system as if the order is already approved/completed

BEFORE:
[image]

AFTER:
[image]

Does anyone have any advice on how to solve these two issues? We are using Magento ver. 1.9.3.9 Thanks!